# Wifi is not working on my Dell E6400

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Dell E6400, everything is working fine, except my wifi.

The switch on the laptop is on but still Ubuntu does not recognize my wireless adapter.

I ran the `lspci | grep` Network command and it shows this:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless
```

Answer (score 4):

If there is a way to connect to the Internet, you can install the following packages in order to use wireless connections.

Open the Software Center and search&find&install these packages:

b43-fwcutter

firmware-b43-installer

or you can install these packages with a terminal command(Short cut:Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

If your pc haven't a another internet connection, you can download driver packages from the following urls.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/b43-fwcutter

http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/firmware-b43-installer

Please, be careful of packages architecture(The packages architecture you will choose must be same as your Ubuntu architecture.)

**After this operation reboot your system and connect a wireless network.**

Comment: FYI both the links are dead now

Answer (score 2):

On my Dell Latitude E6400, running

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo reboot
```

as [proposed by an article on ajopaul.com](http://www.ajopaul.com/2013/01/05/install-wireless-driver-for-broadcom-bcm4322-in-ubuntumint/) resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the 64 bit version of ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS will not recognize my E6500 wifi adapter but the i386 version of 18.04.1 does see it. If anyone has a wifi issue they should check the version they are running, stepping down to 32 bit might help.

Answer (score -1):

That Ubuntu version is quite old. Update your Ubuntu version or install it clean and in the additional drivers tab you may find the driver you are missing. The latest Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 15.04.