# Help wanted to connect to WiFi.

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my dell latitude e6400 and am unable to connect to wifi. No networks show up. It says I don't have the proper drivers, which I can't get without a connection. I'm nowhere near as tech-savvy as I would like to be, therefore I don't know how be more specific than this. If someone could help me figure this out, I would be very grateful, as I'm basically carrying around a glorified paperweight at the moment. I need this computer for school, so time is a bit of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would find an Ethernet cable, plug it and follow this guide to get wifi working: [Wifi is not working on my Dell E6400](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215194/wifi-is-not-working-on-my-dell-e6400)

If finding an Ethernet is an issue for you, you can try to download those .deb files, copy them on a flash drive and install them.